# Where can I find old Holy Office decrees?

Tags: catholicism, resource-request

Where can I find old Holy Office decrees that are not contained in the [*Acta Sanctæ Sedis*](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ass/index_en.htm) (1856-1908) or in the [*Acta Apostolicæ Sedis*](https://www.vatican.va/archive/aas/index_en.htm) (1909-present)?

For example, I want to check out the citations for [canon 1258 of the 1917 Code](https://www.intratext.com/IXT/LAT0813/__P42.HTM) listed here:

> **S. C. S. Off.**, 23 mart. 1656, ad 4; 13 nov. 1669; decr. 20 nov. 1704;
> 9 dec. 1745;
>
> litt. (ad Vic. Ap. Algeriae), 21 ian. 1751;
>
> (Mission. Tenos in Pelopponeso), 10 maii 1753, ad 1;
>
> (Algeriae), 14 sept. 1780;
>
> (Kentucky), 13 ian. 1818, ad 1;
>
> (Queebec), 23 febr. 1820, ad 1, 3;
>
> instr. (ad Ep. Sanctorien.), 12 maii 1841, n.2;
>
> instr. 22 iun 1859;
>
> (Sanctorien.), instr. (ad Archiep. Corcyren.), 3 ian. 1871, n. 2;
>
> (Columbi), 14 ian. 1874;
>
> (Tunkin. Central.), 29 mart. 1879;
>
> (Bucarest), 8 maii 1889; 19 aug. 1891;
>
> instr. 1 aug. 1900;
>
> 24 ian. 1906;

> **S. C. de Prop. Fide** (C. G.), 17 apr. 1758, ad 2;
>
> 15 dec. 1764, ad 3;
>
> (C. G. - Antibar.), 2 aug. 1803, ad 1;
>
> (C. P. pro Sin. - Cochinchin.), 2 iul. 1827;
>
> (C. G.), 21 nov. 1837;
>
> instr. (ad Vic. Ap. Scopiae), 26 sept. 1840, ad 14;
>
> litt. (ad Vic. Ap. Aegypti), 3 maii 1876

I tried to find the last citation in the Acta Sanctae Sedis but couldn't, does anyone know where I should look?

I'm interested in all the citations for the canon except *Ex illa*, *Ex quo*, *Inter omnigenas* and *Dolorem*.

If anyone can help me find any of the above documents or others cited in the canon I'd appreciate it. Any language is good.

Comment: Have you considered emailing Cathy Caridi who maintains the blog [Canon Law Made Easy](https://canonlawmadeeasy.com/)?

Comment: I've emailed her in the past and got no response, but good idea.

Comment: Found a good clue about Footnotes to the 1917 Code [here](https://www.canonlaw.info/masterpage1917.htm), published separately in the 9 volume Codicis Iuris Canonici Fontes that Cardinal Gasparri used.  [This page](https://www.canonlaw.info/canonlaw_17fontes.htm) talks extensively about deciphering the footnotes.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Thank you, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, regarding *communicatio in sacris*.

Some of those citations appear in [Dom Augustine's commentary on can. 1258](https://archive.org/details/1917CodeOfCanonLawCommentary/page/n2581/mode/2up) ([PDF](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=2970) pp. 2717-2723).

[Ed Peters's transl.](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7786) only cites 2 sources for that canon, one of which is:

- ​Szal, Ignatius Joseph. [*The Communication of Catholics With Schismatics: A Historical Synopsis and a Commentary*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9834). Canon Law Studies 264. Washington: Catholic Univ. of America Press, 1948.